# Selenium ChromeOption InvalidArgumentException in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting an InvalidArgumentException when I pass my options argument through. However, the driver still launches - without prompting - when it runs through defining the driver, but won't run further through the code due to the exception (of course).

Minimal Workable Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\mok_z\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") #Replace as Appropriate
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default') #Replace as Appropriate
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\mok_z\OneDrive\Desktop\Music Mailer\chromedriver.exe', options=options) #Replace as appropriate
```

I'm aware the webdriver accepts a few arguments, and was under the impression that the way the options argument was passed is fine. Please let me know where I'm going wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. It appears that it won't accept the profile as an argument, if the profile is already in use on the device. When I closed the offending instance of chrome, there was no exception.

I would still like to know if there is a work around to this, however.